# MVC dropdownlist , data not displaying when model is not Ienumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I am having a problem passing to the View a Model that contains the dropdown data and the model.

With this code my page loads, but the dropdownlist contains "System.Web.MVC.SelectList" when selected.

Here's my controller code.

```
public ActionResult Index(string productNameFilter, string productCategoryFilter, String productTypeFilter )
{
    var ddl = new Items();
    ddl.CategoryddList = itemsRepository.GetItemDdl("Item Categories").Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = c.DropdownID.ToString(),
        Text = c.DropdownText
    });
    ViewBag.CategoryDD = new SelectList(ddl.CategoryddList, "Value", "Text");
    var model = itemsRepository.GetItemByName(productNameFilter);
    return View(model);
}
```

Here's my view

```
@model Ienumerable<Models.items.items>

@Html.DropDownList("productCategoryFilter", 
                   new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryDD), 
                   "---Select Category---")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side note - if you use a ViewModel between the View and the Model instead of binding directly to the model, you can put your SelectList on the ViewModel and use @Html.DropdownFor() instead of @Html.Dropdown().  The ViewBag should really be used sparingly.

However back to your original question:

What is "Items()"? in your line

```
var ddl = new Items();
```

I'm not sure what good reason you would have NOT to make it enumerable.

I suspect it is not working because you are making a selectlist from a select list twice --
in your code behind you are defining ViewBag.CategoryDD as a SelectList(), and then in your Razor code you are creating a new SelectList() from the existing selectlist.  You shouldn't have to do this.

The way I would do this is create a ProductViewModel class that contains your product category list AND your list of products (your current model), and a property for the selected filter.

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Model.items.items> ProductList {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductCategoryList {get;set;} //SelectList is an IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
    public string SelectedCategory  {get;set;}
}
```

Then on your view the model would be

```
@model ProductViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SelectedCategory, "---Select Category---")
@Html.DropdownListFor(model => model.SelectedCategory, Model.ProductCatgoryList)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time to answer this.